# FullCalendar does not fit perfectly on mobile

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, fullcalendar

I am doing fullcalendar on jQuery Mobile,
I have test at chrome's extension, 
window resizer with 320 X 480,
its seem not fits perfectly like image below, some is short some is taller if got event.

how to make it fits perfectly on every mobile device? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behavior of calendar, the more text you add in event the more height you will see for that row.

If you really have to show all rows in same height, you can use an icon for all events and display the text(overflowing with absolute position and z-index) when user taps/clicks on it.